# Property 'selectedHero' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

I learn Angular and I havbe a problem with tutorial. So I'm here https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2 and you can see this line

```
  selectedHero: Hero;
```

Problem is that I have an error

> Property 'selectedHero' has no initializer and is not definitely
> assigned in the constructor.

I found the solution to this problem. I wrote

```
selectedHero!: Hero;
```

It works correctly but it doesn't good practice. Any idea how can I code better?

Comment: from where you get that error message? Never had it. Usually the first approach is just fine

Comment: From terminal and VSC

Answer (score 1):

It is because TypeScript 2.7 includes a strict class checking where all the properties should be initialized in the constructor.

**Workaround:**

1. set the *strictPropertyInitialization* to false in your **tsconfig.json** file

```json
"strictPropertyInitialization": false
```

this will disable the strict checking property initialization for all the project.
2. initialize your properties  with a default value

```js
 selectedHero: Hero = null;
```

3. if you don't like the initialization idea, you can mark the property as optional or make it of Type Hero or undefined:

```js
 selectedHero?: Hero;
// or
selectedHero: Hero | undefined
```

Comment: First method doesn't work. In tsconfig.json I don't have "strictPropertyInitialization" property. I added that but it doesn't work. Second work but what meaning "?" in Angular

Comment: 1-Restart your vscode. 2- "?" Is a typescript notation that means that the property is optional and it might be present or not (defined or `undefined`)

Comment: When I do that I have a problem with ngModel which user this var,

Comment: can you paste how you are using this within your ngModel binding?

Answer (score 0):

Make the property optional

selectedHero ?: Hero;